# Binding static library in xamarin

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin

I'm new to xamarin Can any one please tell me how to bind objective c static library(.a file) in xamarin studio?

I find out one good PDF417 scanner. But the SDK is in pure iOS(objective C).

https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-ios

Anyone please tell me how to integerate that one in xamarin studio?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the official documentation for [Binding Objective-C in Xamarin](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/) for starters.